# Web API: Background tasks - ping of multipe clients (health status of clients)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, background-task

I have a web API which collects data from multiple clients (other workstations/servers) and displays this information to users. I want to show the users if any workstation/server is offline/not available. Because I can not make sure the client is sending an offline command to my API I want to receive this by pinging the workstations repeatedly.

What would be the best approach to achieve this? I am not happy with my solutions so far.

Do I start a background task at the beginning of the start of the IIS application which creates multiple pinging tasks?

Do I have to make a second applications which handles the pinning and only tells my Web-API about the status?

Comment: Have you read this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Some cool stuff. I don't know if it fits my use case completely.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in many ways. I am just describing one solution below which I think best suitable for your task.

**Step 1**: Create a place to store your server status. It can be a SQL database, Azure Storage etc.

**Step 2**: Create an Azure Logic App to call (ping) all your servers in every 5 minutes or something. If you want more accurate and real-time status, then make it short.

**Step 3**: Create API which consume the data that you saved. You can even show your user last time your server was active.

**Step 4**: Client can call at anytime to see the status.

If you want to give any alert when any server is down, you can add logic at your Logic App. There are inbuilt tools to send email from Logic App. If your client is Mobile App, consider sending a push notification to client.

Comment: To clarify you would separate my current web-API with an database and a new application which just handles the pinging? If it would be all in one app then I have already all the steps. But I am not satisfied how I am implemented step 3. Currently I have a lib which calls my ping class periodically. From there I create not awaited tasks for the pinging. Which creates a lot of "not nice code" to handle the result and storage to the database. I am running in problems like lifetime of injections, etc, ... So I am wondering what would be a clean and maintainable way to do it.

Comment: @user3077796 yes, that's why I suggested to sperate the 'ping' logic to another application. So API don't have to do this logic and only focus on delivering existing status data/ log to client.